# Crear una funcion de prioridades

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo:

```
<?php
if($row_s = ['prioridad'] == "normal") {
echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-cate-normal">Normal</span>';
} elseif($row_s = ['prioridad'] == "medio") {
    echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-cate-medium">Medio</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-cate-urgent">Urgente</span>';
}
?>
```

Este modelo de prioridades son 3, este es un ejemplo, los otros son similares.
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es crear una funcion en cual pueda llamar a aca funcion sin tener que estar repitiendo el codigo. No se como hacerlo. No se que tengo que tener en cuenta porque no las entiendo bien.

```
function dato()
```

Por ejemplo: no que funcion cumple dato y tampoco se si dentro del parentesis tengo que agregar algo o no.

Espero me ayuden a comprender un poco mas php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te coloco este ejemplo, primero tengo la variable que recibe el dato donde se especifica la prioridad

```
$prioridad = "normal";
```

Segundo creo una función donde recibo como argumento a la variable anterior para procesarla por dentro de

```
function prioritario($prioridad){
    if($prioridad == "normal"){
        echo "Tu prioridad es normal";
    } else if($prioridad == "medio"){
        echo "Tu prioridad es media";
    }else if($prioridad == "alta"){
        echo "Tu prioridad es alta";
    }else{
        echo "No identifico tu prioridad";
    }
}
```

Por dentro de la función mediante condicionales lógicos compruebo cada una de las 3 posibles situaciones y al final una evaluación *default* para cuando no es ninguna de las prioridades

Al final invoco la función de este modo pasandole la variable como argumento

```
prioritario($prioridad);
```

Como esta variable al incio fue declarada con el valor de *normal* el resultado una vez procesado sería el siguiente

> Tu prioridad es normal

De este modo la función por su nombre es la que es invocada y solo se le pasa como argumento la variable que contiene la prioridad a evaluar

Comment: Esto me sirve para poder programar en bloques y asi llamar por funcion. Ahora lo entiendo mejor! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
function prioridad($prioridad){
    $prioridades= array("normal" => "situacional", "media" => "grave", "alta" => "urgente");
    $tipo_prioridad= array_key_exists($prioridad,$prioridades)? $prioridades[$prioridad] : "no se identifico tu prioridad";
    echo "tu prioridad es: {$tipo_prioridad}";
}

$prioridad="alta";
prioridad($prioridad);
```

Comment: Excelente e interesante solución, te doy + 1

Comment: Gracias, tambien voy a probarlo ya que estoy en modo aprendizaje, je...